# Терминология. Synchronization

Tags: многопоточность, boost

1)

> In designing applications, it's important to differentiate between
>   requirements imposed on bounded code and unbounded code. If your class
>   makes undue requirements on unbounded code, that's usually a sign that
>   encapsulation is out the window.

В разрабатываемых приложениях важно различать требования, наложенные на статический(ограниченный) и динамический(неограниченный) код. Если ваш класс не подходит по требованиям к динамическому(неограниченному) коду, то есть признак что инкапсуляция вышла из окна. 
Что такое "bounded code and unbounded code" и как понять последнее предложение?

2)А это что 
Caller-provided locking и caller-ensured locking?

[Synchronisation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.tutorial.external_locking_____strict_lock__and__externally_locked__classes)

Comment: bounded code, насколько я помню, это связанный код - локализованый (в данном случае) в классе. Несвязанный - задействует функционал, объявленный вне класса. Второе предложение - если класс имеет уникальные требования к несвязному коду, то это признак того, что инкапсуляция выходит за окно

Comment: Caller - это по-нашему "клиент" при клиент-серверной архитектуре. Для детального перевода надо увидеть все предложение (а может и больше для осознания контекста)